# How does Maven plugin prefix resolution work? Why is it resolving "findbugs" but not "jetty"?

Tags: java, maven, maven-metadata

I was doing some testing using Maven and realized that I can execute the `findbugs` goal of the Findbugs plugin without adding the plugin to the POM file. On the other hand, when I needed to run the `run` goal of the Jetty plugin, I was forced to add the plugin to the POM file or the build failed.

- Why Jetty needed configuration in the POM while Findbugs didn't?
- How does Maven know which Findbugs to execute (suppose we have to plugins with the same name but different group id)?

When I run the first command the build is successful without any changes in POM file:

```
mvn findbugs:findbugs
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building module-mytest 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.4:findbugs (default-cli) @ module-mytest ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
     [java] Warnings generated: 6
[INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.165s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 23 18:40:26 WEST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/111M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run the second I get this:

```
mvn jetty:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 30.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 41.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.129s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 23 18:43:27 WEST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/104M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/hp-pc/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

So in order to pass the build I needed to add the following to the pom file:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

#### What is a prefix and why do we need it?

You just encountered the [Plugin Prefix Resolution](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) of Maven. This is a feature which enables the user to invoke goals of a specific Maven plugin, by using its prefix. When you invoke directly a goal on the command-line, you could use the fully-featured form of:

```
mvn my.plugin.groupId:foo-maven-plugin:1.0.0:bar
```

This would invoke the goal `bar` of the Foo Maven plugin having the coordinates `my.plugin.groupId:foo-maven-plugin:1.0.0` (in the form of `groupId:artifactId:version`). It works well, but it is a bit verbose. It would be nice to invoke this goal in a simpler manner, without specifying all those coordinates. Maven makes this possible by assigning prefixes to plugins, so that you can refer to this prefix instead of the whole coordinates, with:

```
mvn foo:bar
    ^^^ ^^^
     |    |
   prefix |
          |
         goal
```

#### How is this prefix determined?

You can define a prefix for each Maven plugin. This corresponds to a simple name used to identify it:

> The conventional artifact ID formats to use are:
>
> - `maven-${prefix}-plugin` - for official plugins maintained by the Apache Maven team itself (you must not use this naming pattern for your plugin, see this note for more informations)
> - `${prefix}-maven-plugin` - for plugins from other sources
>
> If your plugin's artifactId fits this pattern, Maven will automatically map your plugin to the correct prefix in the metadata stored within your plugin's groupId path on the repository.

Put another way, if your plugin's artifact id is named `foo-maven-plugin`, Maven will automatically assign it a prefix of `foo`. If you don't want this default assignment, you can still configure your own with the help of the [`maven-plugin-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/) and its [`goalPrefix`](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/descriptor-mojo.html#goalPrefix) parameter.

#### How does Maven map prefixes to plugins?

In the command

```
mvn foo:bar
```

Maven must have a way to deduce that `foo` actually means `my.plugin.groupId:foo-maven-plugin`. In the `settings.xml` file, you can add [plugin groups](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups), in the form of:

```
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

What this does, is telling Maven which group id it is supposed to consider when you're using a prefix in a command. By default, and in addition to the groups specified in the settings, [Maven also searches the group ids `org.apache.maven.plugins` and `org.codehaus.mojo`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/execution/DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator.java#L110-L114). It searches those default ones after the ones you configured in the settings. Therefore, with the configuration above, and a command of `mvn foo:bar`, Maven will look for a plugin having a prefix of `foo` inside the group id `org.mortbay.jetty`, `org.apache.maven.plugins` and `org.codehaus.mojo`.

The second step is how that search is actually performed. Maven will download metadata files (or look them into your local repository if they are already downloaded), called `maven-metadata.xml`, from each remote repositories at those group ids. If we take the example where the only remote repository we have is Maven Central, Maven will first download [`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-metadata.xml`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-metadata.xml), and look inside this file if we have something mapping `foo`. Notice how the group id was transformed into a directory structure in the remote repository. The structure of this metadata file is:

```
<metadata>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <name>Some Awesome Maven Plugin</name>
      <prefix>somePrefix</prefix>
      <artifactId>some-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</metadata>
```

If none of the `<plugin>` section contain a `<prefix>` that is equal to the one we specified (`foo`), Maven will continue with the next group id, hitting [`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml). Again, if none are found, Maven will finally hit [`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml) (notice the `Downloading:` logs in your `mvn jetty:run` command, exactly fetching those last two files). If none are still found, there is nothing Maven can do for you anymore, and it will error:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'foo' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.mortbay.jetty, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (.../.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

This is the error you have here. However, if one match was made during this search, then Maven can deduce the `<artifactId>` to use.

It now means it has the group id, and the artifact id. The final piece of the puzzle is the version

#### Which version is going to be used?

Maven will take the latest one available, unless explicitly configured in the POM (see next section). All possible versions are retrieved by fetching another metadata file, still called `maven-metadata.xml`, but this time living alongside the artifact id folder in the repository (contrary to the ones above, where it was alongside the group id). Taking the example of the Maven Clean plugin (whose group id and artifact id would be found with the above mechanism and a command of `mvn clean:clean`), the [`maven-metadata.xml`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/maven-metadata.xml) looks like:

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>3.0.0</latest>
    <release>3.0.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
      <version>2.0-rc1</version>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <!-- more versions -->
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20151022205339</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Maven [will select as version](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/version/internal/DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java#L159-L168) the `<release>` version, which represents the latest release version of the plugin. If that tag isn't there, it will select `<latest>` which represent the latest version of the plugin, release or snapshot. It can happen that both tags are not there, in which case, Maven [will select the first release, or the first snapshot for lack of a release](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/version/internal/DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java#L175-L227), of the list of `<version>` elements.

If that still fails, there is nothing Maven can do for you anymore, the version couldn't be deduced and it errors. This isn't very likely to happen though. We now have gathered the group id, the artifact id, and the version; time to finally invoke the `bar` goal of our plugin.

#### What's the issue with my configuration?

As said above, Maven looks in certain pre-defined group ids inside the active remote repositories to look for matches with a given prefix. With the command

```
mvn findbugs:findbugs
```

Maven starts the search with the `findbugs` prefix. Since our configuration does not have any `<pluginGroup>` in our settings, Maven looks into `org.codehaus.mojo` and `org.apache.maven.plugins` group id for a prefix match.

And it does find one: [Findbugs Maven Plugin](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/index.html) is published under the `org.codehaus.mojo` group id; indeed, you can find it [in the `maven-metadata.xml`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml):

```
<plugin>
  <name>FindBugs Maven Plugin</name>
  <prefix>findbugs</prefix>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

And you can also find the version that is going to be used by peeking into the [`maven-metadata.xml`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/findbugs-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml) file under the `findbugs-maven-plugin` just deduced (3.0.4 at the time of this writing; and notice how it exactly matches the version in the `mvn findbugs:findbugs` logs of your question). So the resolution succeeded, and then Maven can continue to invoke the [`findbugs`](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/findbugs-mojo.html) goal of this plugin.

The second example is the command

```
mvn jetty:run
```

As before, the same resolution steps happen, but, in this case, you'll find out that the prefix `<jetty>` does not appear in any of the `maven-metadata.xml` for the group ids `org.codehaus.mojo` and `org.apache.maven.plugins`. So the resolution fails, and Maven returns the error that you have.

But we've seen how to make it work! We can add a `<pluginGroup>` inside our settings, so that this group id can also be searched during resolution. The [Jetty Maven Plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html) is published under the group id `org.eclipse.jetty`, and if we peek into the corresponding [`maven-metadata.xml` in Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/maven-metadata.xml), you'll see that `<prefix>jetty</prefix>` is there. So the fix is simple: just define this new group id to search inside the settings:

```
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>org.eclipse.jetty</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Now, Maven will also look into this group id, and match the `jetty` prefix to the `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin` successfully.

#### How can I use a specific version? Or, I don't want to modify my settings!

Of course, all of this resolution can be side-tracked if you define the plugin explicitly in your POM, which is the other solution you found:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
</plugin>
```

and use

```
mvn jetty:run
```

If you configure the plugin directly in the POM, the prefix resolution still happens, but it is a bit masked: Maven will download the plugin from the configured remote repositories, and will download and install all metadata files along the way, including the `maven-metadata.xml` containing the mapping for the prefix `jetty`. So since it downloads it automatically, the search always succeeds.

Note also that since the plugin was defined in the POM, you wouldn't need any `<pluginGroup>` in the settings: the group id was written in the POM. Furthermore, it makes sure that the version 9.2.11.v20150529 is going to be used, instead of the latest.

Comment: That was a comprehensive explanation, exactly what i was looking for.Thanks.