# No plugin found for prefix 'war' in the current project and in the plugin groups [] available from the repositories

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jboss, resteasy

I'm trying resteasy webservice  [example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/resteasy/creating-jax-rs-web-service-using-resteasy-example/).

getting **No plugin found for prefix 'war' in the current project and in the plugin groups [] available from the repositories** error in the pom.xml file.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.javacodegeeks.areyes</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-sample</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>resteasy-sample Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>JBoss repository</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>resteasy-sample</finalName>
</build>
```

already added M2_HOME and path in environment variable.
how can i resolve it?

Comment: You can check solution here: http://corlang.blogspot.in/2014/09/no-plugin-found-for-prefix-war-in.html

Comment: If you want to know what a prefix is, [refer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205664/how-does-maven-plugin-prefix-resolution-work-why-is-it-resolving-findbugs-but/40206597#40206597). Your particular issue is just caused by failed previous download attempts, so run Maven wih `-U` flag.

Comment: Just added correct mvn path in eclipse and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute maven-war-plugin

Comment: what are the steps?