# How to fix "No plugin found for prefix 'liquibase' in the current project and in the plugin groups"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I am new to Liquibase. I have already included maven plugins and liquibase to my pom.xml however when i update liquibase using `mvn liquibase:update` I get this error:

```
No plugin found for prefix 'liquibase' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
```

How can I fix this error so that when I type `mvn liquibase:update` it will run properly

Here are some of the dependencies that are in my `pom.xml` related to liquibase

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<build>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: Could you please share your pom.xml with us?

Comment: I already edit my post and included some plugins in my pom.xml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you are in the right path when you are executing `mvn liquibase:update` command. And also try to run the command in a separate terminal like command prompt. In my case I'm using the terminal in IntelliJ IDEA when I had the problem but when I tried it in different terminal, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 27):

I don't think the problem is with liquibase plugin itself. It's more about maven prefixes.

Try  executing: `mvn org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:update`

Also, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205664/how-does-maven-plugin-prefix-resolution-work-why-is-it-resolving-findbugs-but).

Answer (score 4):

In my case problem was in path. I was trying to start command `c:\mvn.cmd liquibase:status` from wrong folder.

Running from `c:\projects\My_current_project\mvn liquibase:status` works like a charm. `c:\projects\My_current_project\` is folder, where `pom.xml` is.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was my pom is configured in such a way that the liquibase plugin is only defined under certain profiles which need to be passed in before the `mvn liquibase:<your command here>` gets run.

for example, if the pom.xml has a `local` profile and your liquibase plugin is ONLY defined under that profile, you should run something like `mvn -P local liquibase:update` in order for maven to pick up liquibase (since it's only defined in that profile)